# Solr: empty query

Tags: solr

I've added a document into my solr core:

```
$ curl http://192.168.121.49:8983/solr/arxius/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="authors_ca">Bon dia nois</field></doc></add>'
```

Nevertheless, I'm not quite figure out why it doesn't appear on a simple search:

```
$ curl http://192.168.121.49:8983/solr/arxius/select?q=*%3A*

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what the field type applied to it

Comment: if it is of string type then the text is not tokenised and you have to pass the exact word ...

Comment: you are not committing the data....in your curl query commit=true is missing

Comment: your command should be curl http://192.168.121.49:8983/solr/arxius/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="authors_ca">Bon dia nois</field></doc></add>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below command to add the document to solr.

```
curl 192.168.121.49:8983/solr/arxius/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="authors_ca">Bon dia nois</field></doc></add>'
```